# I'm having a blank output when using def functions

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in python I'm trying to use def function and every time I run the code it gives me a blank output. I'm using pyroid3 in my phone since I dont have any laptop/desktop.

I'm trying to get thru with this code

```py
def greet():
    print('hi')
```

Comment: You have to call your function `greet()`

Comment: The code in your question only _defines_ the function named `greet`, but never calls it. Since you're not calling the function, it never runs

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your function. With `def` you only declare it.
In python we calling function by adding `()`.
Like this:

```
def greet():
    print('Hello')
    

greet()
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if it is an obvious question but have you tried to call your function? For example try to add `greet()` at the end of your code. It will look like this:

```
def greet(): 
    print('hi')
greet()
```

Feel free to ask if you need explaination!

Comment: Got it mate! Thanks so much. Sorry, im really new at this and I'm very interested in learning it. I dont have much any background in programming. Glad I found this community.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that the output isn't displaying because you're not calling the function.

```
def greet():
    print('hi')

# Call the function
greet()
```